# Why is my value only being set after the app is opened and closed for the first time in swift?

Tags: swift, boolean, admob

I have a value, showAds, that determines wether or not the user has purchased noAds or not. If it is true then ads are displayed. It works for the most part, except for when the user opens the app for the first time it does not show ads. If they close out the app and open it again, then ads show as they should. How do I fix this? Thank you, any help is appreciated!

Here is all of the code associated with that value:

```
var showAds = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "showAds")



func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    if showAds == true {

        view.addSubview(bannerView)

    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "showAds")

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let appDefaults = ["showAds" : true]
    userDefaults.register(defaults: appDefaults)
     print("SHOWING ADS: \(showAds)")

    if showAds == true {

        self.view?.addSubview(bannerView)

    }

    if showAds == false {


        bannerView.removeFromSuperview()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the stored property with the default value which is being assigned at the moment of your view controller's initialization. The viewDidLoad method is called after that (more info about the view controller lifecycle [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW3)).

Since at the first launch of your app your user defaults are empty, your stored property is set to "false" and will keep this value until you change it **directly**.

If you want to have a property which will be fully dependent on your user defaults value, the best choice is a computed property:

```
var showAds: Bool {
    return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "showAds")
}
```

> [...] computed properties do not actually store a value. Instead, they provide a getter and an optional setter to retrieve and set other properties and values indirectly.

More info about different property types in swift [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_374)